# Работа с бд на java

Tags: java, sql

Есть две некие таблицы в бд, в них записаны свойства объектов, условные стулья и столы. Помимо прочих свойств как "цвет, вес" есть оценочная стоимость. Нужно реализовать возможность нескольких оценочных стоимостей для каждого из этих объектов, но что бы по запросу вызывался последний по дате. Сейчас эти данные хранятся в таблице того же объекта, а при вызове притягивается текущая дата.

Comment: и что бы не искать последнюю дату, хранить ссылку на текущую цену или в таблице стульев или в специальной таблице текущих цен. или помечать строки в истории цен "переходящим" полем

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте таблицу InvertoryCost (id, inventoryId, cost, date, ...)
join эту таблицу и

```sql
SELECT 
  "Все поля",
  MAX(Date) AS LatestDate
FROM 
  ... 
  LEFT JOIN InventoryCost
    ON InventoryCost.inventoryId = ...Id
    
GROUP BY 
  "Все поля"
```